# Read Raw Json File In Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON File in this format.

[image]

I want to preprocess this data. For that, I converted these data to CSV using a pip module called [jsoncsv](https://pypi.org/project/jsoncsv/). How do I read this JSON file from pandas without converting this to CSV using an external pip library? I looked at this [page](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.json.read_json.html) on the pandas docs but I think this json structure does not belong to any of the 5 orient parameter types.

```js
{"ip":"10.1.1.1","data":{"ssh":{"status":"connection-timeout","protocol":"ssh","error":"dial tcp 10.1.1.1:22 i/o timeout"}}}
{"ip":"10.12.4.7","data":{"ssh":{"status":"connection-timeout","protocol":"ssh","error":"dial tcp 10.12.4.7:22: i/o timeout"}}}
{"ip":"10.21.5.5","data":{"ssh":{"status":"connection-timeout","protocol":"ssh","error":"dial tcp 10.21.5.5:22 i/o timeout"}}}
{"ip":"10.12.6.2","data":{"ssh":{"status":"connection-timeout","protocol":"ssh","error":"dial tcp 10.12.6.2:22: i/o timeout"}}}
{"ip":"10.21.6.4","data":{"ssh":{"status":"connection-timeout","protocol":"ssh","error":"dial tcp 10.21.6.4:22: i/o timeout"}}}
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your json such that we can copy/paste and not as screenshots.

Comment: Do you want to use `pandas` or `jsoncsv`?

Comment: I want to use pandas.

Comment: @SahanRandika - What you provided is not a valid json. Does it have a [ ] around it ?

Comment: No it doesn't have [], That is why I previously mentioned it doesn't belong any of the 5 types orient parameter. But this file has converted to csv using the jsoncsv without any problem.

Comment: @SahanRandika this is **not a JSON file**. Rather, it is in JSON-lines format (essentially, a newline delimited format of JSON objects on each line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pandas.json_normalize`:

```
import json

d = json.loads(open("test.json").read())
df = pd.json_normalize(d)

>>> df

          ip       data.ssh.status  data.ssh.protocol                      data.ssh.error
0   10.1.1.1    connection-timeout                ssh    dial tcp 10.1.1.1:22 i/o timeout
1   10.12.4.7   connection-timeout                ssh  dial tcp 10.12.4.7:22: i/o timeout
2   10.21.5.5   connection-timeout                ssh   dial tcp 10.21.5.5:22 i/o timeout
3   10.12.6.2   connection-timeout                ssh  dial tcp 10.12.6.2:22: i/o timeout
4   10.21.6.4   connection-timeout                ssh  dial tcp 10.21.6.4:22: i/o timeout
```

###### test.json:

```
[{"ip":"10.1.1.1","data":{"ssh":{"status":"connection-timeout","protocol":"ssh","error":"dial tcp 10.1.1.1:22 i/o timeout"}}},
{"ip":"10.12.4.7","data":{"ssh":{"status":"connection-timeout","protocol":"ssh","error":"dial tcp 10.12.4.7:22: i/o timeout"}}},
{"ip":"10.21.5.5","data":{"ssh":{"status":"connection-timeout","protocol":"ssh","error":"dial tcp 10.21.5.5:22 i/o timeout"}}},
{"ip":"10.12.6.2","data":{"ssh":{"status":"connection-timeout","protocol":"ssh","error":"dial tcp 10.12.6.2:22: i/o timeout"}}},
{"ip":"10.21.6.4","data":{"ssh":{"status":"connection-timeout","protocol":"ssh","error":"dial tcp 10.21.6.4:22: i/o timeout"}}}]
```